# How do I access global/window scope from inside a worklet? (javascript frontend)

Tags: javascript, html, audio-worklet

I create an AudioWorkletProcessor and I activate it like this:

```
audioCtx = new AudioContext();
await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule('testworklet.js');
mysource = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'testworklet');
mysource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

In testworklet.js I define

```
class TestWorklet extends AudioWorkletProcessor {    
    constructor(options){
        super(options);
        this.s = WebSocket('wss://localhost') // ERROR: WebSocket is undefined!
    }
    process(inputs, outputs) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But this code cannot access WebSocket because WebSocket is in the "window" scope, while the code is run under the AudioWorkletGlobalScope.

How do I javascript?

Comment: what about window.WebSocket('wss://localhost')?

Comment: tried: window is undefined

Comment: If it's not tricky, it can be helpful to share your demo proj. It can be some other problems that window is undefined and you know "WebSocket" is under "window".

Comment: Can you try a workaround? You could pass the window or maybe WebSocket object as a second parameter in the constructor.

Comment: @Wo997 I tried that as well, but what you pass as "options" needs to be serializable.

I solved my problem with a different workaround, I believe that was the intended solution, I posted my answer below. Thank you everybody for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution: you don't.

A more thorough look to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioWorkletProcessor) revealed the **port** attribute: the [MessagePort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MessagePort/message_event) allows sending of messages between the Processor and the Worklet itself. Since the processor cannot access anything I extended the worklet to do the i/o work and sent the data to the Processor. Here is the code:

In the worklet (main script) I can access everything. I get my data and I send it to the worker through the port

```
        class MyWorkletNode extends AudioWorkletNode{
            constructor(){
                super(audioCtx, 'testprocessor');
                var p = this.port;
                socket.on('audio_data', function(msg){
                    p.postMessage(msg['data']);
                });
            }
        }
        audioCtx = new AudioContext();
        await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule('testprocessor.js');
        mysource = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'testprocessor');
        mysource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
```

In the processor I just receive the data from the worklet through the port (and not directly):

```
      class TestProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {    
          constructor(options){
            super();
            this.port.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
              this.ondata(event);
            } );
            this.port.start()
          }
```

Note: I changed the name that was inaccurate before: testworklet.js to testprocessor.js